# Dart The method 'setRng' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart, setter

I made a class and not sure why my getter is fine but the setter is showing as not defined in flutter.

```
class Test {
  int range = 1000;

  set setRng(int val) => range = val;

  get getRng => range;
}
```

`Test.getRng` no errors..

`Test.setRng(100)` throws the error `The method 'setRng' isn't defined for the class 'Test'`

Clearly they're both defined..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Dart, you invoke setters with `setter = value;`. So your code can be modified like this:

```dart
test.setRng = 0;
```

Getters and setters make member functions look like member variables. By convention, they can then have variable like names, for example:

```
class Test {
  int _range = 1000;

  set range(int val) => _range = val; // optionally perform validation, etc

  int get range => _range;
}
```

now it looks more natural when you use:

```
test.range = 123; // using the setter
print(test.range); // using the getter
```

Comment: The error message for this in flutter is awful I have to say. If I write `test.setRng` it's red underlined and says it's not defined. Clearly this is wrong and should say it's missing a parameter or something.

Comment: Message is correct, but should include hint about setters.